# NSDateFormatter with custom string inbetween

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm new to iOS app development. It will be great if someone helps me. I have a `NSDateFormatter` with the date format like `M/d/yy hh:mm a` and it displays correct result as

```
3/24/2016 12:00AM.
```

But i want to add String

> `at` in between date and time. Expecting result as

`3/24/2016 at 12:00AM`

Comment: Does nobody read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)? ;-) This case is described literally.

Comment: Format date and time separately and put them into predefined template `%@ at %@`. That's the only way you can make the format properly localized. Don't harcode strings like `at`, keep them localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format could be something like

`M/dd/yyyy' at 'hh:mm a`

3/24/2016 at 12:00 AM

You can check this [link](http://gtiapps.com/?p=1086) for further details.

`Format String       Output String
M/d/y               11/4/2012
MM/dd/yy            11/04/12
MMM d, ''yy         Nov 4, '12
MMMM                November
E                   Sun
EEEE                Sunday
'Week' w 'of 52'    Week 45 of 52
'Day' D 'of 365'    Day 309 of 365
QQQ                 Q4
QQQQ                4th quarter
m 'minutes past' h  9 minutes past 8
h:mm a              8:09 PM
HH:mm:ss's'         20:09:00s
HH:mm:ss:SS         20:09:00:00
h:mm a zz           8:09 PM CST
h:mm a zzzz         8:09 PM Central Standard Time
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z   2012-11-04 20:09:00 -0600`

You can combine any of the options as per your requirements.

Comment: Fantastic.. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To do it properly, with localization in mind, you will have to localize `at`, too:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

// load date format from localization files
NSString *dateFormat = @"%1$@ at %2$@"; //NSLocalizedString(@"my_date_format", @"My date format");

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSString *localizedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:dateFormat, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date], [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

NSLog(@"%@", localizedDate);
```

Also note that I didn't hardcode date formats but I have used the ones defined by the user (language & region settings) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `M/d/yy' at 'hh:mm a` as formatter.

Comment: I would advise against this format which will be terrible for most users (US only format?)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for swift Language.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy"
var result: NSString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
result = NSString(format: "%@ at %@", result,timeFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
print(result)
```

Also, if you are doing development in Objective C then you can use below code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"M/dd/yyyy";
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@",result,[timeFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: Why do this the hard way? Use one format string. There is no need to create two formatters and append the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"];

NSDate *date = [dFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mm a"];

NSString *dateStr = [dFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: You have to quote the "at". `MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mm a`.

Answer (score 0):

So replace

```
"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
```

fomatter by

```
"MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mm a"
```

Comment: @HarishP So just share the code and outcome to let see what exactly "not works"

Comment: It will work if you properly quote the text. Use `MM/dd/yy 'at' hh:mm a`.